# .NET's CLR in WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor

I'm trying to understand the point of WebAssembly from a .NET angle.

From the [Blazor FAQ](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/wiki/FAQ#q-how-can-you-run-net-in-a-web-browser):

> Running .NET in the browser is made possible by a relatively new
>   standardized web technology called WebAssembly.

That's a weird claim.

Obviously you can run .NET code in the browser without WebAssembly by cross-compiling it to JavaScript (eg. with [JSIL](http://jsil.org/)). That just sucks because

1. The CLR's object model is more sophisticated than JavaScript's (eg. you can make a compact array of integers, `Uint8Array`, but not of a more complex value type in JavaScript) making the translation of certain types of code very inefficient.
2. .NET's native base library implementations need to be implemented in JavaScript too, which is a lot of work.
3. The browser ecosystem is based on JavaScript so there's friction if you use such cross-compilations.

So the FAQ's meaning is that it's now *practical*, right?

I struggle to see how WebAssembly helps with any of these points though. A cursory glance suggests that its virtual machine still shouldn't be able to efficiently represent the CLR properly (still no complex value types, right?). And the other two points will hold no matter what.

So what changed? What exactly does WebAssembly bring to the table that wasn't possible with JavaScript alone? Is it really just that Webassembly is stack-based and JS itself isn't? Why should that be that big a deal?

EDIT: Couldn't be happier about Henk's super-to-the-point answer. For the interested, I now found [a great rationale page](https://webassembly.org/docs/rationale/).

Comment: Running your "native" .net assemblies via a CLR that has been compiled to WASM, allows you to debug your .Net code running in the browser in Visual Studio. Seems like a win-win scenario to me. No cross-compilation of .Net assemblies and I can program the full stack in C#

Comment: @phuzi Can’t see why a browser feature is a necessity for that. That’s a tooling issue.

Comment: What it brings to the table isn't additional features, but speed and [the ability to write code in your preferred language](https://github.com/appcypher/awesome-wasm-langs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> suggests that its virtual machine still shouldn't be able to efficiently represent the CLR properly

Correct. That is why Blazor first deploys a compiled-to-WASM version of Mono.
Blazor brings its own CLR to the party.

Your application code won't be compiled to Wasm, it will be deployed as (regular) IL that is executed by Mono. With the dev tools you can see a bunch of .DLL files being downloaded to your browser. You can in principle use any .net standard package that fits within the Browser security sandbox.

> What exactly does WebAssembly bring to the table that wasn't possible with JavaScript alone?

It enables a C compiler to compile Mono.*.c to Mono.wasm.
And it is fast.

Comment: Oh, wow. Now I get it. Amazing stuff. I found a link to a rationale now. Added it to the question.